# What's the difference between qmlRegisterSingletonType & setContextProperty in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

When I want to expose a C++ to QML interface.

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType<Interface>("Test", 1, 0, "Interface",
                                 [](QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine) -> QObject * {
    Q_UNUSED(engine)
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)
    return Interface::instance();
});
```

or

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("Interface", Interface::instance());
```

Which way shall I choose? the only difference is `Singleton` need to `import` the module, and `setContextProperty` is setting a real global object to QML.

Comment: Anyone, if your class is not a singleton then you must use setContextProperty

Comment: This is a good overview : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html

Comment: The instance of singleton is created only on demand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setContextProperty` sets the object as value of a property in the very root node of your QML tree, so it basically looks like this:

```
property var myContextProperty: MySetContextObject {}
ApplicationWindow {
    Item {
        Button {
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This has various implications:

1. You need to have cross-file references possible to files that are not "local" to each other (main.cpp and wherever you try to use it)
2. Names are easily shadowed. If the name of the context property is used somewhere else, you will fail to resolve it.
3. For name resolution, you crawl through a possible deep object tree, always looking for the property with your name, until it finally finds the context property in the very root. This might be a bit inefficient - but probably no big difference.

`qmlRegisterSingletonType` on the other hand enables you to import the data at the location where you need it. So you might benefit from faster name resolution, shadowing of the names is basically impossible and you don't have intransparent cross-file references.

It needs to be noted, that `qmlRegisterSingletonType<T>` does not enforce that the type `T` you register is indeed a singleton! The only thing that is required that you have an object with a static function, that returns a instance of type `T`, and that this instance is constant. So you might have two classes `SingletonProviderA` and `SingletonProviderB` or whatever, that have the necessary functions with the necessary signature, that returns an object of type `T` (and not `SingletonProviderA` or `SingletonProviderB`). So you can register two instances of the same type as singleton to QML. If I remember the documentation right, you should set the ownership to the engine.

Downsides of having singletons:

1. You can not easily shadow them. You need to register them or the creation of the object that imports them will fail. So using `qmlscene` might be impossible (At least I have not managed to use it)
2. ...

---

I use both concepts. I tend to like the Singleton better, since it allows you to implement your stuff more module-orientated.

However I usually import it only in the "root" of such module, and pass the value later as property to the other objects in the module. So I don't have every file coupled to the singleton.

If I use context properties, I decide a special naming convention to protect me from shadowing. I also prefer to only access it as context property in my main.qml, and further on pass it explicitly to the child objects.

Comment: Qt 5.15 and Qt 6.X's QML_SINGLETON macro simplify the singleton registration process. It requires three qmake entries and the macros QML_ELEMENT + QML_SINGLETON after Q_OBJECT. cmake is supported but only for Qt 6.2 and later.